# MS Access Partial String Query

Tags: sql, string, ms-access

I am trying to run a query that will return the names that match. For example, I have one table called UserNames. In User names there are records like this: "Fields, Sally L.". In another table, called Customer, I have a column for first name with the name Sally and a column for Last Name with the name Fields.

How can I run a query to match them? In essence, I think I need to use a like operator and or also the InStr function. But I am not sure how to actually do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
SELECT t1.UserName
FROM UserNames t1, Customers t2
WHERE t1.UserName Like "*" & t2.FirstName & "*" 
      And t1.UserName Like "*" & t2.LastName & "*"
```

Comment: Do I need to have a join here? When you say FROM Usernames t1, that just means from the table called UserNames right? I don't  need to put that t1 there, correct?

Comment: You do not need a join, it would not work. t1 and t2 are aliases, if you do not include the alias, you will have to add the table name to all fields / columns. Aliases are considered to be good practice.

Comment: Thank You. I am trying it out now.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 't1.UserName Like "*" & t2.First Name & "*" and t1.UserName Like "*" t2.Last Name & "*". I think this is because Access needs brackets or parentheses because my field names have spaces? I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you must bracket field names with spaces `[Last Name]`, but it would be much better to get rid of the spaces.